# ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'authen.CustomUser' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

(I've been through all the other questions)I wanted to customize default user model. that's why i created a fresh django project and haven't done migrations. i just wrote the code and saved it
settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'authen',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authen.CustomUser'
```

manager.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email is required")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,**extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)
        
        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError("Super user must have is_staff true")
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

models.py of authen app

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .manager import UserManager
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    nid = models.CharField(max_length=17,unique=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True, null=True)

    objects = UserManager()
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'CustomUser'
```

i haven't done any migrations and i'm using latest django and python3.1. i had to create several project for this reason. Ask me if more info is needed.

Comment: the main problem is the `app_label = 'CustomUser'`, perhaps you meant `verbose_name='...'` or something similar.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes but that wasn't the the case maybe. i solved the problem and answered it below.

Answer (score 0):

Chatgpt was the worst for this 4 hours of debugging. I just added authen app in install_apps before django.contrib.auth

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'authen',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

and in my models

```
class Meta:
        app_label = 'authen'
```

and it worked.